# How to implement this php code

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

So I have this php code in my joomla site (joomla's latest article module) and I'd like to add a bootstrap tooltip to the title of my links. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I add this script to a php page. Thanks in advance. Here's the script i got from w3schools.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>
```

**and my code which i already have.**

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_articles_latest
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<div style="float: left;margin-right: 47px;">

<ul class="latestnews<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
<?php foreach ($list as $item) :  ?>
<li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $item->title; ?>" itemprop="url"><img src="/images /sound.png" />&nbsp;
        <span itemprop="name">
            <?php echo $item->title; ?>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: just put that script block in your header and include the jquery library somewhere else on the page and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi thanks for comment. The page doesnt load once i put the js script into it the way it is. Just to be sure (since i am very new to php) between the <?php  (this is head?)  ?> would be the header right?

Comment: Negative. You need to add that java script into the `<head></head>` section of your html.

Comment: is that chunk of code included in another document, or is there more to this document that is not shown? this is not a complete document on its own.

Comment: like i said im working on a JOOMLA site. This is a php document for the latest articles module from joomla. All i want to do is add tooltips to titles in a list element. If some one can help me impliment js into a php document then maybe i can do the rest.

Comment: Well we need to figure out where to add it, which is why I am asking what the rest of the document looks like.

Comment: Do you really have that space in the src? Did you read https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_add_tooltips_to_your_Joomla!_website?

Comment: YOu'll be way better off asking on the stackexchange joomla site.

Answer (score 1):

Please enter the following code inside  below defined('_JEXEC')

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration('
$(document).ready(function(){
$(\'[data-toggle="tooltip"]\').tooltip();   
});

');
```

It will include the script into header automatically

Comment: fortunately this code didnt cause my homepage not to load but I still the tooltips arent showing. I already have bootstrap and jquery .js on my site (used with other modules and stuff) so dont think its needed on this php document? Unfortunately I can post the url so anyone have any idea why bootstrap tooltip not showing. Thanks for your response Knight Rules.